# How to turn off an electrical installation with a simple cheated plug?

Tags: short-circuit

Theoretically, would it be possible to do a short circuit with a cheated plug?

How can cheat it?

---

Added:

[Wikipedia on "cheater plug"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheater_plug)

- A cheater plug, AC ground lifter or three-prong/two-prong adapter is an adapter that allows a NEMA 5-15P grounding-type plug (three prongs) to connect to a NEMA 1-15R non-grounding receptacle (two slots).[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7lTe.jpg) The use of such an adapter avoids the need to replace receptacles, but is potentially hazardous, if the grounding tab is not actually connected to electrical ground.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2OmZ.jpg)[3] An alternative identified in the U.S. and Canadian electrical codes is to replace the outlet with a GFCI breaker outlet.[3]

**Cheater Plug** [from here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Cheater_plug_edited.jpg) (Wikipedia)

A cheater plug, with metal grounding tab (the leftmost blade and cavity are wider, for polarization purposes)

[image]

Comment: You mean you want to trip the breaker?

Comment: @kellenjb The all electric circuit.

Comment: What is the electric circuit that you speak of?

Comment: @kellenjb A simple electric circuit of a garage.

Comment: It is difficult to tell what is being asked here.  The course of action is clear.

Comment: We don't know what plug it is you are talking about or what you are cheating or what the electric circuit of a garage is.

Comment: You need to CLEARLY describe what you mean using many simple words. The following ords or phrases are not understood. | "Cheated", "The all electric circuit", "How can cheat it". When you say "cheated" do you mean "shorted" as in "short circuited"? as In "Would it be possible to short out an electrical circuit by plugging in a plug which has a short circuit across its terminals".

Comment: Re "The course of action is clear" --> Yes, the course of action needed in cases like this in general is to develop a methodology for dealing with questioners whose primary language is not English. In this case probably Basque Espanol (Donostia). If there are Spanish speakers here they may be able to help get the question put more clearly in English. | Just bopping would be members on the head and shovelling them off the site seems to be the inferior option when there are probably others who would be very happy to help.

Comment: **Any Spanish speakers here?** If so you may be able to help improve this question.

Comment: Guys - "Cheater Plug" is standard technical jargon in some USA power and audiophile circles. Your not knowing it should not adversely penalise a questioner - it is well enough used that it would not be obvious to many that it would be an unfamiliar term. (FWIW - I also had never heard it before either).

Comment: Yes, I'm sure we all know what a "cheater plug" is, but the question is not clear. Is it possible to short a circuit with a cheated plug? yes?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - It's great that you've tried to educate the user, but you've changed the question a lot and it's still not answerable. The original question is *How to turn off an electrical installation with a simple cheated plug? Theoretically, would it be possible to do a short circuit with a cheated plug? How can cheat it?* which doesn't make any sense.  WRT "Any Spanish speakers here?" I've had 4 years of Spanish, and nothing but the implied subject 'I' in "How can cheat it" is identifiable.  If you want to ask and self-answer "What are cheater plugs and are they safe?" go ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not completely obvious what you are trying to do **BUT** it's almost certainly not safe. You may kill yourself or somebody else.

If you can explain in much more detail and simple  words we may be able to help. (Small and simple because language differences mean more complicated words may be misunderstood.)

---

"Cheater Plugs" = mains power adapters that break the connectivity of the earth circuit, are sometimes used in audio systems to remove ground connections which are causing "hum loops". This is a very dangerous practice which can lead to electric shock.

[image]

In the text below "GFCI" = Ground Fault Current Interrupter =  device to remove power automatically if even a very small amount of the current is bypassed improperly by eg your finger. If you get a shock then it turns off (almost) instantly. Using GFCIs is a very very good idea.
 [Lots and lots of references to GFCIs](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=%22cheater+plug%22&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvnsfd&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=sv5qT66YHIa6iQfo56WIBg&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CA8Q_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=1038#hl=en&safe=off&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=gfci&oq=gfci&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&gs_l=img.3..0l10.9647l10261l4l10720l2l2l0l0l0l0l232l450l2-2l2l0.&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=b1bff6192db305d4&biw=1920&bih=1038)

The following was written with USA installations in mind but also applies in Spain.

---

**Wikipedia notes:**

**(1) Use of Cheater plugs can kill** [image]

- ... The cheater plug is also recognized as a safety hazard in laboratory settings. For example, in August 2005, Tarun Mal, an associate professor at Cleveland State University, was electrocuted when he plugged a defective fluorescent lamp into a time switch using a cheater plug.[8] Subsequently, the state of Ohio issued seven citations to the university for unsafe electrical conditions.[8] The Scientist notes that four of the University's seven environmental safety experts agreed that use of the cheater plug "is not uncommon in US university labs".[8] Jim Kaufman, CEO of the Laboratory Safety Institute, says, "When you inspect labs, it's not unusual to find anywhere from one to seven that way."[8]

**(2) Alternatives - only one is safe:**

- There are several alternatives for connecting newer appliances to two-prong receptacles without rewiring the building: removing the grounding pin of the plug, replacing the receptacle with a three-prong outlet, or replacing the receptacle with a GFCI; **only the last (GFCI) is safe.**

  - **Removing the grounding pin of the appliance’s plug is unsafe, and leaves the appliance without proper grounding even when relocated and plugged into a properly grounded three-prong receptacle.**

  [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hs0YL.png) Additionally, since most NEMA 5-15P plugs have both current-carrying prongs the same width and rely on the ground pin for correct orientation, removing it allows insertion of the plug with hot and neutral wires reversed, creating an additional hazard.

  Replacing the receptacle with the three-prong type and leaving the ground screw unconnected is **just as unsafe as using a cheater plug**, but has the additional disadvantage that subsequent users of the outlet may not be aware that it is not properly grounded. However, if the ground screw of the receptacle is connected to the neutral side, electric shock is possible even if the appliance is properly functioning. This is called a "false" or "bootleg" ground and is a serious safety hazard[9] often undetected by common receptacle testers.[10]

  **Replacing the receptacle with a GFCI receptacle is the safest alternative.** If a GFCI receptacle is properly functioning, then it will shut off the power to a faulty appliance to prevent electric shock. As a safe option that protects all appliances plugged into that receptacle, the National Electrical Code permits such replacement if the installer marks the GFCI as having "No Equipment Ground".[3]